# General Exception, unable to get compiled [bytecode]

Tags: solidity, remix, error, bytecode, verify

Hi I created a smart contract using Remix, I deployed the contract but now that I try to verify my contract on  BscScan I keep getting the following error:  Error! Unable to generate Contract Bytecode and ABI (General Exception, unable to get compiled [bytecode], what am I doing wrong? Please help. )[image]

Comment: Is your contract having a single solidity file (without any imported contracts or so) or having multiple files or imports? And, have you deployed your contract using Remix, on BSC mainnet?

Comment: yes, single solidity file. And yes I deployed it from Remix.

Comment: Have you deployed the contract on BSC mainnet or testnet ?

Comment: no, I deployed my contract from Remix, I am new to all of this, so I have very limited knowledge. Sorry. Do I have to deploy again on BSC or Testnet again, since I had already deployed from Remix?

Comment: Actually, on Remix only, it shows the connected network in the top-left side under **Deploy & run transactions** menu. If you've deployed on **BSC mainnet**, then is this your deployed contract: https://bscscan.com/address/0x469fb91b15c52657ea0ed6707d13851c73b7fef7 ?